# How to call a function with 2 different parameters?

Tags: pine-script

I have a function with 2 parameters. the 1st is the source and the second is the number of candles to the left.

I want to watch 10 candles left and again 20 candles left so I try to call this function twice (1st time with argument 10 and the other 20) with operator "or"

Here is the code:

```
lbR = 4
rangeUpper = 60
rangeLower = 5

_inRange(cond) =>
    = ta.barssince(cond == true)
    rangeLower <= bars and bars <= rangeUpper
        
function_Macd(_src, _lbL) =>
    plFound = na(ta.pivotlow(_src, _lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
    phFound = na(ta.pivothigh(_src, _lbL, lbR)) ? false : true
    oscLL = _src[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, _src[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
    priceHL = close[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, close[lbR], 1)
    bull = priceHL and oscLL and plFound
        
result = function_Macd(macd, 10) or function_Macd(macd, 20)
```

The script compiles without error but next to the name of the indicator there is an exclamation mark: "Memory limits exceeded. Study allocates: 1.1 times more than allowed."

Is there another way to write this code in order to optimize it?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing in your script that would cause that error, however _inRange is not listed above and it seems to be another function called. That may be the cause.

Just streamlining above

````
function_Macd(_src, _lbL) =>
 plFound = ta.pivotlow(_src, _lbL, lbR)
 phFound = ta.pivothigh(_src, _lbL, lbR)
 oscLL = _src[lbR] < ta.valuewhen(plFound, _src[lbR], 1) and _inRange(plFound[1])
 priceHL = close[lbR] > ta.valuewhen(plFound, close[lbR], 1)
 bull = priceHL and oscLL and plFound

result = function_Macd(macd, 10) or function_Macd(macd, 20)```
````

Comment: Thank you for your reply... I have updated the code. I tried with ta.pivotlow(_src, lbL, lbR) but it does not work.. However, this piece of code is part of a screener script and in the parameters at the top of the indicator there is max_bars_back=501 and if I delete it then it works. The question is: according to you is this parameter necessary knowing that to display the symbols of the screener I use if barstate.isrealtime? Thanks

Comment: when u use valuewhen and find a pivot, the pivotlow returns the value of the pivot (low or high) so you do not need to use _src[lbR], u can simply use plFound for the value. ```ta.valuewhen(plFound,plFound,1)``` and i do not know what _inRange function does, but it needs to return bool (true/false) and not certain why it is checking the bar prior value of plFound, if plFound is true (there is a pivot), then the one prior would not be a pivot and would always be false